# How to return a type related with parameter in a generic method?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a method that returns an object or colletion related with given generic type parameter. 
Here is the structure:

```
public interface IBaseClass{
}

public class AnEntityClass:IBaseClass{
    public string SomeValue { get; set }
}

public class AnotherEntityClass:IBaseClass{
    public string SomeValue { get; set }
}

public class TestClass<T> {
    public string AnotherValue { get; set; }
    public T GenericValue { get; set }
}

public TestClass<List<AnEntityClass>> AMethodReturnsGenericList(){
    return new TestClass<List<AnEntityClass>>();
}

public TestClass<AnotherEntityClass> AMethodReturnsAnObject(){
    return new TestClass<AnotherClass>();
}
```

I tried an approach showed below, but it gave an compile time error.

Converting it first object then `TestClass<T>` works but it doesn't seem a good solution to me.

What is the correct way of doing that?

```
//cannot implicitly convert ....
public TestClass<T> DoSomeWork<T>(string methodType)
{
    if(methodType=="collection")
        return AMethodReturnsGenericList();
    else if(methodType=="object")
        return AMethodReturnsAnObject();

}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if someone called `DoSomeWork<string>("collection")`? `AMethodReturnsGenericList()` doesn't return a `TestClass<string>`... Are you really sure that `DoSomeWork` should be a generic method at all?

Comment: Does adding a constraint 
` where T:IBaseClass `  solve the problem you mentioned? 
Actually what I want to do is that.
I have a number of methods that return  generic type and I want to write a method that works as router method and that is exposed to other classes.
@JonSkeet. When I consider your answer, it looks like a design problem.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You could still call `DoSomeWork<SomeEntirelyDifferentEntityClass>`, for example - what would you expect to happen then?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is still error prone. 
It's not a case a generic method can be used as far as I understand from your answers.
What is your suggestion for that case @JonSkeet ?

I have some methods and they are  returning  TestClass<T> in which T can be AnEntityClass or  AnotherEntityClass.

How can I write a proxy method that is exposed to other classes and it calls the methods I mentioned above and returns the result of them?

Comment: I don't understand enough about what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid. At the moment I'd suggest just having different methods, given that you can't easily express what the signle method should return in a safe way.